# single jms consumer for multiple jms servers

Tags: jms, weblogic, middleware

I am using a distributed jms queue and weblogic is my app server. There are three jms servers deployed in my clustered enviroment. The producers just send the message using name of queue jndi lookup 'udq' for example. Now I have associated a consumer for each jms server and I was able to consume the message, no problem so far.

Here is question, can I have a single consumer to consume the messages from the 3 jms servers. The weblogic allows jndi naming for destination lookup with following syntax @

```
            qsession1 = qcon1.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            qsession2 = qcon2.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            qsession3 = qcon3.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

            queue1 = (Queue)ctx.lookup("JMSServer-1@UDQ");
            queue2 = (Queue)ctx.lookup("JMSServer-2@UDQ");
            queue3 = (Queue)ctx.lookup("JMSServer-3@UDQ");
            qreceiver1 = qsession1.createReceiver(queue1);
            qreceiver2 = qsession2.createReceiver(queue2);
            qreceiver3 = qsession3.createReceiver(queue3);
            qreceiver1.setMessageListener(this);
            qreceiver2.setMessageListener(this);
            qreceiver3.setMessageListener(this);

            qcon1.start();
            qcon2.start();
            qcon3.start();
```

I have only one OnMessage implemented for the above consumer. This does not work. Any suggestions please..

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't have a consumer receiving messages from more than one JMS server. A consumer can receive messages from only one JMS server. You need to create multiple consumers to receive messages from multiple JMS servers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply shashi, I just found that the jni JMSServer-1@UDQ does not work, now I am only using one consumer per jms server. I have no exceptions while I start the consumer. If I use jni as UDQ which is the name of the queue it works fine. The syntax appears to fine according to the weblogic documentation.

Comment: What if two clients connect to the same server ex. hostA? If there is jms.jndi.provider.url=t3://hostA:31122,hostA:31124 it shouldnt care about a server. It should discover messages from this two nodes not only from node which client is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

you can use "Queue Forwarding" function. 
From online documentation of wls 10.3:

"Queue members can forward messages to other queue members by configuring the Forward Delay attribute in the Administration Console, which is disabled by default. This attribute defines the amount of time, in seconds, that a distributed queue member with messages, but which has no consumers, will wait before forwarding its messages to other queue members that do have consumers."

here a link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/jms/dds.html#wp1260816

You can configure this feature from administration of each single queue.